# Variable inside Variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, getopts

Hey I have the following problem:

```
FILE=/etc/squid3/conf.d/$CUSTOMER.conf
```

Everytime i'm doing that:

```
grep -o $replaced_ip $FILE
```

> grep: /etc/squid3/conf.d/.conf: Data not found

I've startet the script together with the `$CUSTOMER` variable, so it is not empty.
Guess I'm having a syntax error?
Thanks for any advice.

```
while getopts :c:s:d:hI:p:r:l:fa: FLAG; do
  case $FLAG in


        s)
                SOURCE=$OPTARG
                ;;

        d)
                DESTINATION=$OPTARG
                ;;

        I)
                ISSUE=$OPTARG
                ;;

        c)
                CUSTOMER=$OPTARG
                test -e /etc/squid3/conf.d/$CUSTOMER.conf
                customer_available=$?
                ;;
```

Comment: please post the customer variable initialization as well

Comment: Customer is quite obviously empty...

Comment: $CUSTOMER is inside getopts

Comment: @tso post your getops line

Comment: while getopts :c:s:d:hI:p:r:l:fa: FLAG; do
  case $FLAG in


        s)
                SOURCE=$OPTARG
                ;;

        d)
                DESTINATION=$OPTARG
                ;;

        I)
                ISSUE=$OPTARG
                ;;

        c)
                CUSTOMER=$OPTARG
                test -e /etc/squid3/conf.d/$CUSTOMER.conf
                customer_available=$?
                ;;

Comment: put it in the description

Comment: And how do you call the script?

Comment: Have you tried removing the first ':' and seeing if getopts reports an error? What are the args that getopts parses (i.e. can you provide a command-line example)?

Comment: The error message *Data not found* is odd. I have never seen it with grep. Which grep are you using? As for the error message: Can you reproduce it from the command line? To do this, turn on `set -x` just before the grep statement in your script, so that you see what is actually executed (you can turn it off, `set +x`, afterwards).

Comment: Your `while/case` are missing `esac/done`: clease create a complete example. AFAIK you might have an option `f) echo "f: Todo"` without `;;` where your CUSTOMER os changed again.